# GCP PostgreSQL receives fast shutdown request for no reason, why is that?

Tags: spring, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, cloud, persistence

I looked into the logs and found that my database receives a fast shutdown request.

Why does this happen and what do the other logs indicate?

[image]

Comment: Did it come back up again?  If I had to guess, i would say Google is preparing to do a version upgrade, or maybe a hardware migration.

Answer (score 1):

Both messages are related with connections that tried to connect to your application when a fast shutdown signal was received due to a change on the instance's configuration, like changing a flag, changing the storage, operations with SSL certificates, assigning IP’s, etc, all the operations that causes your instance to restart to be applied successfully.

To prevent these errors in the future, I'd recommend you to perform any operation that requires the instance to be restarted when there is low traffic (maybe by the time frames when the maintenance window is configured) to prevent any error in your application.